# warning in vSphere CLI: Use of uninitialized value $hostname

Tags: perl, vmware, vsphere, pacemaker, stonith

I am using [vSphere CLI 6.5.0](https://my.vmware.com/de/web/vmware/details?productId=614&downloadGroup=VS-CLI-65) for resetting a VM from a Perl script. This is in the context a (proprietary) STONITH plugin for Pacemaker.

Immediately after STONITH, `journalctl -u pacemaker` reports a warning in `vmcontrol.pl`, which belongs to vSphere CLI. The warning is reported by `fence_legacy`, which belongs to Pacemaker.

```
Use of uninitialized value $hostname in concatenation (.) or string at 
/opt/vmware-vsphere-cli-distrib/apps/vm/vmcontrol.pl line 168.
```

The error occurs in a call to `UTIL::trace` in this context:

```
sub reset_vm {
   foreach (@$vm_views) {
      my $mor_host = $_->runtime->host;
      my $hostname = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $mor_host)->name;
      eval {
        $_->ResetVM();
        Util::trace(0, "\nvirtual machine '" . $_->name . "' under host".
                                  " $hostname reset successfully ");
      };
```

I am wondering whether this is a feature or a bug. Could it be that [`Vim::get_view`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/doc/perl_toolkit_guide_idx.html) communicates with VMware at a time where the hostname cannot be reported (and hence `$hostname` cannot be initialized) because the VM is rebooting?

It sounds unlikely (e.g because the call to `ResetVM` occurs after the assignment to `$hostname`), but I suspect something like this is going on, in which case the warning could be ignored. I also suspect that the problem is related to vSphere CLI alone (i.e. is not caused by its use inside a Pacemaker stack).

Comment: As a standalone script, I'm not hitting any issues with vmcontrol. I'm not familiar with the other two items. Have you tried running vmcontrol as a standalone script?

Comment: @KyleRuddy That's what I'm also planning to do. I'll report back here once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one instead.

```
sub reset_vm {
   foreach $mor_host(@$vm_views) {
     my $hostname = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $mor_host->runtime->host, properties => );
      eval {
        $_->ResetVM();
        Util::trace(0, "\nvirtual machine '" . $_->name . "' under host".
                                " $hostname reset successfully ");
      };
```

Comment: Thx, but the script `vmcontrol.pl` is part of VMware's vSphere CLI product, and I don't want to touch/patch that at all.